# C++ istream is read() always binary?

Tags: c++, ifstream, eof, istream

I have a function that has an std::istream argument and uses the member functions read() and eof() on it. Someone may pass in a subclass ifstream,ofstream,fstream,etc and I don't know if it is in binary mode.  My questions:

Is there any way to determine whether or not the istream is an ifstream,ofstream,fstream,etc and has been opened in binary mode?

Do read() or eof() have any differences on the istream depending on the subclass? Let's say an ifstream in text mode is the argument, if I call the istream read() and eof() am I in binary or text mode, and is this covered by the standard?

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    ofstream out("test", ios::trunc|ios::binary);
    char a[] = "before \x1a after";
    out.write( a, (sizeof a) - 1);
    out.close();

    ifstream in("test");
    char buffer[(sizeof a) - 1];
    // read one less than the actual file size
    in.istream::read(buffer, (sizeof buffer) - 1);
    buffer[in.gcount()]=0;
    cout << "gcount: " << in.gcount() << endl;
    cout << "eof: " << in.istream::eof() << endl;
    cout << buffer << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `read` call will be properly handled by the underlying [`std::filebuf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf) object (if it's a file stream). In fact, the stream classes are basically just proxies to a [`std::streambuf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf) object. End of file is end of file no matter the stream.

Comment: Oh, and if you have an `istream` argument, then you can't get an `ofstream` passed to the function. Also, I guess it's actually a `istream` *reference*, as streams can't be copied.

Comment: @Joachim I don't know what you mean by "End of file is end of file no matter the stream". I just tried putting 0x1a in the middle of a small 10 byte file and opening it as a `ifstream file("filename")` and then I did `file.istream::read(buffer,10)` to test, and it only read to the EOF character, not the whole file. So it looks like the file would have to be opened in binary mode. In other words the EOF found by istream is different depending on if I'm using `ios::binary` to open the ifstream. Thanks for the ofstream correction, my mistake.

Comment: There are no special byte sequence that means "end of file". The streams end-of-file flag is set only once you try to read from beyond the end of the file, just like e.g. C `FILE` handles, or basically any other kind of file handling concept in about all operating systems. The [`eofbit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate) is *never* set due to some byte in the stream. It doesn't matter if the stream is in binary mode or not.

Comment: @Joachim When I add 0x1a byte and don't open in binary mode then it detects that as end of file and eof() is true even though it isn't the end of the file.

Comment: Then you're either have a bug in the standard library (which is highly unlikely) or you're doing something weird. Can you please edit your question to include a small but correct code sample (e.g. a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/))?

Comment: @Joachim http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Uc7Z8Sqd I tested using gcc and visual studio.

Comment: Tested the code, and it works as expected. If you're wondering about the missing `"r"` in `"after"` it's because you read one byte less than the size of the file. Change the size of `buffer` to be the same as `a` and it should read that last byte as well.

Comment: @Joachim I purposely read one byte less than the size of the file to demonstrate that the eofbit is set once 0x1a is encountered, before the entire file has been read. I appreciate your help but I'm concerned we aren't understanding each other. I'm using `gcc-4.6.3` and I get `gcount: 7` , `eof: 1`, `before `.

Comment: The `eofbit` flag is set with that program? Thats really weird, because it should't happen. Have you checked the size of the file, if everything is written? Have you tried with other compilers, or another version of GCC?

Comment: @Joachim Yes I got the same results in Visual Studio 2010. I just tried in Ubuntu 13 and got `gcount: 13`, `eof: 0`. On Windows the EOF character is 0x1a and on Linux there is none (apparently) so that probably explains what's happening.